# Unable to run test on Chrome in Travis-Ci

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, travis-ci

I am working on JavaScript and Node.js project and I'm very new to Travis-Ci.

I have configured `.travis.yml` according to project requirement :

```
language: node_js
node_js: 
 - node
os: windows
addons:
 chrome: stable
script: 
 - npm test
```

But, after adding all the necessary tags still, I'm facing some issues related to the Chrome browser.
After any commit, the 'Travis-Ci' will run the tests and shows the passing results, and then showing the below error:

```
 Smoke Suite : 

    √ Verify that User is able to Sign in with existing Email Team credentials.

  1 passing (11ms)

    
The command "npm test" exited with 7.
    > 
    > C:\Users\travis\build\username\tavis-demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:962
    >     throw err;
    >     ^ WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary   (Driver info: chromedriver=90.0.4430.24
    > (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}),platform=Windows
    > NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

If anyone has a solution for this please respond.
Thanks!

Comment: You really don't want to run Chrome from inside the CI (at least if it's not run on your machine with a GPU) that's a recipe for flakiness - you're better off using a browser grid vendor like browsrstack/saucelabs/browserling/amazon df etc

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for your response. what if i want to do this only with the Travis-ci machine. Can you elaborate more on it actually, i didn't get you correctly.